# Nsdate function: between Objective c

Tags: iphone

I have such a task here

Write a function: between? (Time, start, end), where time, start, end: time in format "hh: mm"

for example, "23:15". The function should return TRUE, if "Time" falls between the 'Start' and 'End'. Case End < Start, for example ("23:11" "8:05") should be considered as: from 'Start' to 'End' the next day.

I have done so

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [­[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [­[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
NSDate * time = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"24:00"];
NSDate * start = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"23:50"];
NSDate * end = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"03:00"];

if(start<time)
{
if (end>time)
{
NSLog(@"YES");
}
}
```

but how do a background check In order to test the next day?
as in the example,
have any ideas?

Comment: Hint:  Set the timezone of the date formatter to GMT, or it will drive you crazy.

Comment: and not as a will not work format HH: mm?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you could do is verify if `end < start` and add +24 hours to `end` in that case. Then just verifying if `time > start && time < end` will solve it.